# Is it an anti-pattern to nest async/await?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I have getAction1, 2 and 3 functions that perform some actions in the backend API service.

I need to have a button that performs getAction1, 2 and 3 sequentially.

In this situation,

Is it better to do this? (OPTION.1)

apiconsumer.js

```
export const getAction1 = (param1) => new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
      // DO SOMETHING AND RETURN 'resolve' or 'reject'
    });
export const getAction2 = (param2) => new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
      // DO SOMETHING AND RETURN 'resolve' or 'reject'
    });
export const getAction3 = (param3) => new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
      // DO SOMETHING AND RETURN 'resolve' or 'reject'
    });
```

button.js

```
const handleOnClick = async (event) => {

    const response1 = await getAction1(param1);
    const response2 = await getAction2(param2);
    const response3 = await getAction3(param3);

// DO SOMETHING...

  };
```

Or do this? (OPTION.2)

apiconsumer.js

```
export const getAction1 = (param1) => new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
      // DO SOMETHING AND RETURN 'resolve' or 'reject'
    });
export const getAction2 = (param2) => new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
      // DO SOMETHING AND RETURN 'resolve' or 'reject'
    });
export const getAction3 = (param3) => new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
      // DO SOMETHING AND RETURN 'resolve' or 'reject'
    });

export const performActions =  async (uData) => {
    const response1 = await getAction1(uData.param1);
    const response2 = await getAction2(uData.param2);
    const response3 = await getAction3(uData.param3);

    };
```

button.js

```
const handleOnClick = async (event) => {

    const response1 = await performActions(uData);

// DO SOMETHING...

  };
```

Basically, OPTION.2 create a nested async/await functions.

I am not sure if it is a good idea to nest async/await like the OPTION.2 above.  If none of these are good, what do you suggest?

Comment: `DO SOMETHING AND RETURN 'resolve' or 'reject'` seems odd, doesn't the Promise constructor ignore its return value? Do you mean that something eventually *calls* `resolve` or `reject`?

Comment: Option 2 looks like the option 1 with an extra step to me.

Comment: Why don't you just use `async/await` in all your code, imo it's much more readable, also you might want to `promisify` things instead of returning a promise each time.

Comment: I think this is more a code organization question than a Stack Overflow question. It depends on where all `performActions` calls will be used. (If more than one other module than `button` will use it, it would make sense for `apiconsumer` to export the `performActions`, to make things DRY)

Comment: If your functions don't need to get the returned value of each previous function, why don't you use `Promise.all`? You're blocking each function until previous one is done.

Comment: @axle94, async/await doesn't block though it appears to. In reality an asyncFunction with an await returns Promise immediately. Any awaits are equivalent to internal .then()s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use Promise all

If the results are not relying on one another.

```
await Promise.all([
  getAction1(uData.param1),
  getAction2(uData.param2);,
  getAction3(uData.param3);
])
```

Comment: You must remember that this has an entirely different effect that you would expect from sequential `await` calls; also, I find it quite ugly to mix Promise.all() pattern with `async/await`, especially when you can accomplish `Promise.all` with `await`s easily.

Comment: @PiotrMa'niak incorrect you cannot accomplish the same result using individual await's. each one would pause the code while it waits for a response, where as the promise all will start all the requests simultaneously saving a lot of time waiting for server to respond.

Comment: Parallel vs sequntial.

Comment: @JoeLloyd: of course you can:
`const a = getAction1(); const b = getAction2(); const c = getAction3();result = [await a, await b, await c]`

Comment: @PiotrMa'niak I stand corrected, I was not aware of this use. But promise all is much clearer DRY syntax. Promise all should be used over arrays of awaits.

Comment: @JoeLloyd - it's "clearer DRY syntax" when you're used to one over another ;) But there's no point arguing such details - I just personally stand for more expressive solutions than DRY-above-all (eg. if/else over a?b:c)

Answer (score 1):

To me it's quite obvious to abstract away as much business logic from the "view" as possible. In this case your button seems to be the "view". Doesn't really matter whether actions 1, 2, 3 are async or not, to me they belong in some layer that deals with the business logic, not the display.

It's not the matter of whether it's elegant to "nest" (or rather "aggregate") `async/await`, because you sure can. Most of the complex front-end APIs work that way and you definitely should do it.

However, whether they should be aggregated right after being declared in the `apiconsumer` - or at some other level - depends on the particular feature you're implementing.

Ask yourself:

1. Does the `performActions` function make sense as a single "operation"? If you can easily name it - that's definitely the case.
2. Is `performActions` related to the other functions in the `apiconsumer`? It seems that it's more abstract so maybe there is some intermediate layer "between" those two places you can put it, like a "service" or "controller"? I guess that you designed `apiconsumer` to be just a list of endpoints and basic calls, it would be good not to pollute it with more complex functions.
3. Will the error (rejection) be caught at the event listener? If so, will it be ok to combine all 3 exceptions into one handler?

In general it always worked out for me to split my app into those "sorta MVC" layers:

1. View, i.e. the display - your components and the DOM manipulation
2. Model - api calls - as dumb as possible; plus some inevitable data formatting logic
3. Controller - everything else, things that you need to compute, calls you need to synchronize, etc.

This is just the basic idea, you can tweak it and play with it anyway you need.

Also you can use some ready architectures that are there, like redux, mobx, etc. If you don't want to get stuck with those "frameworks", you can at least take your inspiration on how to structure things.